# Authentication of devices and gateway in OpenMTC

Tags: authentication, cloud

I'm studying fog-cloud-iot systems and I bumped into OpenMTC.
In order to understand better how their systems work, I would like to know how the authentication between edge devices and gateway and from gateway to cloud works.

Thank you :)

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. This is a middleware protocol for applications.

Answer (score 1):

According to their (sparse) [documentation](https://www.open-mtc.org/platform.html#features), they use certificate-based TLS to authenticate devices.  Perhaps other have more details.

**Edit**:

More information on [authentication can be found here.](https://fiware-openmtc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication/index.html)

Comment: I've read this but my question is, suppose that we have a network of constrained devices for example a lorawan network, how does the gateway itself authenticates and takes his role inside the network? At this level our devices as long as they are constrained may no know what certificates are, obviosly we don't have this problem on the gateway <-> cloud side as long as we can suppose that both elements are evolved enough to communicate at full stacks protocols. Devices for example in L.wan are authenticated with OOTA and APB procedures, same example can be done e.g for BLE Mesh.

Comment: Added more info